Get user token without using LogonUser
How can I get a token of a user that isn't logged in? If the user is logged in, that's easy; You use WTSQueryUserToken. But if the user isn't logged in, it seems that the only way is to use LogonUser API. But I analyzed both UAC (svchost.exe -knetsvcs -p -s Appinfo) and PsExec, and they don't use LogonUser API at all but still get a token from the given user. How is that possible? I thought maybe UAC is using an undocumented API since it's the Microsoft itself but what about PsExec?
I booted a Windows 11 machine up and logged in as a limited user. Then ran an application as admin entering a local admin's credentials. Then repeated this action. When I checked the  Logon Session Id using Process Explorer, I noticed that the Logon Session Ids are different. It means that the UAC actually creates a session for each "Run as Admin" action without calling the LogonUser.


"How can I get a token of a user that isn't logged in?" - you can't. "PsExec ... don't use LogonUser API at all but still get a token from the given user. How is that possible?" - read this article for how PsExec works, but TLDR it simply impersonates the account that is running it over the network, unless you specify a username+password then it logs in to that account on the remote machine.

@RemyLebeau It uses WNetAddConnection2W but I couldn't figure out how adding a network connection can lead to a user's token. The API doesn't even return a handle. But about the UAC? How the UAC creates a token without LogonUser?

It means that the UAC actually creates a session for each "Run as Admin" action without calling the LogonUser. - no. when user with admin logon interactive - system create 2 logon sessions (link it by self)-one filtered and one elevated. uac simply run new process in elevated session (if user admin). if not admin - need enter admin credentials and really will be new session. about LsaLogonUser you dont know ? in anycase - question is about ?

You clearly don't have sufficient knowledge on the topic and everything is mixed up. What is the actual problem?

@RbMm The problem is that I have to create an elevated interactive process in a limited user's session (the only session in the system. admin is not logged in) and I try to understand how UAC and PsExec do this properly. Because when I get an admin user's token using LogonUser and set sessionId to the limited user's session, the process runs elevated but the GUI is black. But UAC and the PsExec does this properly. Since there is no resource in this matter, I decided to reverse them.

so ask actual and single question. you have done very many wrong assumptions here.

for instance how uac work - if user is admin and confirm elevation - system simply get ready elevated user token. and run process with this token. when admin login interactive - system create 2 tokens - elevated (admin) user token and filtered(restricted). and 2 logon sessions (linked each one to other). so in this case not need any new logon. simply system take unfiltered user token. if user not admin - uac request some another admin user credentials. and do logon with it. so elevated app run in this case as another user

nobody create elevated interactive process in a limited user's session. at first in any case - logon session will be another. at second - if user not admin - nobody create for it elevated token. elevated process run in this case as another user.

and if you want access resource on share/another comp - you at all ask wrong questions and not listed. i at begin ask - this is domain or 2 separate workstation - user itself can access share on another comp ( domain case) or need provide some separate credentials for access resource on another comp ? if first case - enouth run process with this user token. so faster second case. user by self have no rigths on remote comp. so you need provide this via NetUserAdd. so no matter under which user you run at all. matter are you call NetUserAdd or not. credentials saved per logon session

as result it and not work when use bu self start process with elevated user token. because session is another and nobody call NetUserAdd in this logon session

@RbMm This is the exact case: My service running as SYSTEM has local admin's credentials (which means I can use LogonUser without a problem). Only 1 user is logged on the system: a limited user. Now my service has to create an elevated GUI application when something happens. Since the local admin is not logged in, I can't user WTSQueryUserToken, my only option is LogonUser. But when I create a token via LogonUser, get linked token, set sessionId with SetTokenInformation and create process with CreateProcessAsUser and GUI is black on the limited user's desktop.

@MustafaChelik this is because you not set logon group sid in token. you need got this sid from user token (your loggen in user) and pass it to LsaLogonUser via LocalGroups parameter

@RbMm ok this is brand new information for me. Can you please explain more? Thank you for your comments. Appreciate it

query you current user token (get it with WTSQueryUserToken)  for TokenGroups. search for SE_GROUP_LOGON_ID sid ( this is something like S-1-5-5-H-L or NT AUTHORITY\LogonSessionId_H_L ). and you need have same sid in groups, with your new token. because desktop UI grant access to this S-1-5-5-H-L (so you need exactly (H,L) luid, not random). if you have no such sid - no access and black UI

I found this code that lists group tokens and then finds the SE_GROUP_LOGON_ID. So I have to get token via LogonUser, then list the newly created token's TokenGroups, then put the LOGON SID in the group and then use SetTokenInformation to update its TokenGroups? https://www.installsetupconfig.com/win32programming/accesscontrollistaclexample3_4.html
